# PHP $_POST not sending data from form

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to send data from a form to my database but I can't seem to do it for some reason. I have tried a bunch of stuff, all troubleshooting that I know, but I guess that this is something beyond the scope of my database knowledge -- only a month or two in. These are the two files that I am trying to send data between, but to no avail. Can someone please explain what is going on?! Thanks so much!

maintenanceReps.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Maintenance : Reps</title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    margin-top: 114px;
}
.style2 {
    border-width: 0px;
}
.style3 {
    color: #000080;
    font-size: 26pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: right;
}
.auto-style2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style3 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center><a href="http://acadweb1.salisbury.edu/~vg7308/premiereProductsHome.html">
<span class="style3">
<img alt="" src="img2.gif" width="100" height="100" style="float: left" class="style2">    </span></a><span class="style3">Rep Maintenance<hr></span></center></body>
<table align="center" class="auto-style3">
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">Rep Num:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="repnum" value="< =$_POST['REP_NUM']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">Last Name:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="lastname" value="<?=$_POST['LAST_NAME']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">First Name:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="firstname" value="<?=$_POST['FIRST_NAME']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">Street:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="street" value="<?=$_POST['STREET']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">City</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="city"  value="<?=$_POST['CITY']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">State:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="state"  value="<?=$_POST['STATE']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">Zip:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="zip" value="<?=$_POST['ZIP']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">Commission:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="commission" value="<?=$_POST['COMMISSION']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">Rate:</td>
        <td> <input type="text" maxlength="32" name="rate"  value="<?=$_POST['RATE']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style2" colspan="2">

            <?php var_dump($_POST); ?>

            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type = "submit" name ="Insert" value = "Insert" />
                <input type = "submit" name = "Search" value = "Search" />
                <input type = "submit" name = "Modify" value = "Modify" />
                <input type = "submit" name = "Delete" value = "Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are     you sure you want to delete this rep?')" />
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<?php include "repsAdd.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

repsAdd.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Maintenance : Reps</title>
</head>
<?php
session_start();


//address error handling

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
//define the Rep Number php variable name

//attempt to connect

if($connection = @mysql_connect ('localhost', 'username','password')){
//print '<p>Succesfully connected to MySQL.</p>';
}
else{
die('<p>Could not connect to MySQL because: <b>' .mysql_error() .'</b></p>');
}
if (@mysql_select_db("GIULIANA_PREMIERE",$connection)){
//print '<p>The GIULIANA_PREMIERE database has been selected.</p>';
}
else {
die('<p>Could not select the GIULIANA_PREMIERE database because: <b>'.mysql_error().'</b></p>');
}

//output the resulting query table
if(isset($_POST['Insert'])){
if(empty($_REQUEST['repnum']) || empty($_REQUEST['lastname']) || empty($_REQUEST['firstname']) || empty($_REQUEST['street']) || empty($_REQUEST['city']) || empty($_REQUEST['state']) || empty($_REQUEST['zip']) || empty($_REQUEST['commission']) || empty($_REQUEST['rate'])){
    print "There is information missing from your form.";
}
else{
    $repnum = $_POST['repnum'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $street = $_POST['street'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $commission = $_POST['commission'];
    $rate = $_POST['rate'];

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO REP VALUES ('$repnum', '$lastname', '$firstname', '$street', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$commission', '$rate')");
    print "Succesfully inserted rep";

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM REP WHERE REP_NUM = '$repnum'";
    if($r = mysql_query($query2)){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
            print "{$row['LAST_NAME']}, {$row['FIRST_NAME']}<br>";
            print "{$row['STREET']} {$row['CITY']}, {$row['STATE']} {$row['ZIP']}<br>";
            print "<b>{$row['REP_NUM']}</b> | $ {$row['COMMISSION']} | {$row['RATE']}<br>";
        }
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['Modify'])){
    if(empty($_REQUEST['repnum']) || empty($_REQUEST['lastname']) || empty($_REQUEST['firstname']) || empty($_REQUEST['street']) || empty($_REQUEST['city']) || empty($_REQUEST['state']) || empty($_REQUEST['zip'])  || empty($_REQUEST['commission'])  || empty($_REQUEST['rate'])){
    print "There is information missing from your form.";
}
else{   
    $repnum = $_POST['repnum'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $street = $_POST['street'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $zip = $_POST['zip'];
    $commission = $_POST['commission'];
    $rate = $_POST['rate'];

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE REP SET REP_NUM = '$repnum',LAST_NAME = '$lastname', FIRST_NAME = '$firstname',STREET = '$street', CITY = '$city', STATE = '$state',ZIP = '$zip', COMMISSION = '$commission',RATE = '$rate' WHERE REP_NUM = '$repnum'");
    print "Succesfully Modified Rep";

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM REP WHERE REP_NUM = '$repnum'";
    if($r = mysql_query($query2)){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
            print "{$row['LAST_NAME']}, {$row['FIRST_NAME']}<br>";
            print "{$row['STREET']} {$row['CITY']}, {$row['STATE']} {$row['ZIP']}<br>";
            print "<b>{$row['REP_NUM']}</b> | $ {$row['COMMISSION']} | {$row['RATE']}<br>";
        }
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['Delete'])){
if(empty($_REQUEST['repnum'])){
    print "There is information missing in your form.";
}
else{
    $repnum= $_POST['repnum'];
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM REP WHERE REP_NUM = '$repnum'");
    print"Succesfully deleted Rep";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: obvious **mysql is bad use mysqli** comment.

Answer (score 0):

all the input elements should be in your form tag, use this html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Maintenance : Reps</title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    margin-top: 114px;
}
.style2 {
    border-width: 0px;
}
.style3 {
    color: #000080;
    font-size: 26pt;
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.auto-style1 {
    text-align: right;
}
.auto-style2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style3 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <a href="http://acadweb1.salisbury.edu/~vg7308/premiereProductsHome.html"> <span class="style3"> <img alt="" src="img2.gif" width="100" height="100" style="float: left" class="style2"> </span></a><span class="style3">Rep Maintenance
    <hr>
    </span>
</center>
</body>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align="center" class="auto-style3">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Rep Num:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="repnum" value="< =$_POST['REP_NUM']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="lastname" value="<?=$_POST['LAST_NAME']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="firstname" value="<?=$_POST['FIRST_NAME']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Street:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="street" value="<?=$_POST['STREET']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">City</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="city"  value="<?=$_POST['CITY']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">State:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="state"  value="<?=$_POST['STATE']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Zip:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="zip" value="<?=$_POST['ZIP']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Commission:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="commission" value="<?=$_POST['COMMISSION']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">Rate:</td>
            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="rate"  value="<?=$_POST['RATE']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2" colspan="2"><input type = "submit" name ="Insert" value = "Insert" />
                <input type = "submit" name = "Search" value = "Search" />
                <input type = "submit" name = "Modify" value = "Modify" />
                <input type = "submit" name = "Delete" value = "Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are     you sure you want to delete this rep?')" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
    include "repsAdd.php";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of your `input` fields are outside of your `form` opening and closing tags.  Also your form action need to point to `repsAdd.php`

```
<form action="repsAdd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- All form elements in here -->
</form>
```

Comment: notice that he includes repsAdd.php so that part is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

your form inputs aren't inside   tags.

bascily youre executing an form with only buttons and no inputs

also you might want to escape the data your getting php.

Answer (score 0):

HTML (XML) is a hierarchical structure so you must put all related `<input>` elements in your `<form>` Tag.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You need following changes in all queries

```
`REP_NUM` = '$repnum' etc
```